# Python Multiprocessing Error?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have been studying multiprocessing module in Python for few days.

However, I have met a strange problem that I cannot resolve it.

The source code is very simple but I cannot get any results after running this code.

The code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as multi

def worker():
    print "Worker!!!"
    return

jobs = []

for i in range(5):
    p = multi.Process(target = worker)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

I was expecting to get a five time of printing "Worker!!!".

However, the only thing I've got is

*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***

">>>"

">>>"

Does anybody who has a idea to solve this problem??

Please DO HELP ME!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to [`multiprocessing documentation`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

> **Note**
>
> Functionality within this package requires that the __main__
>   module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming
>   guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some
>   examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples **will not work in
>   the interactive interpreter**.
>
> ...
>
> *Safe importing of main module*
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python
>   interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
>   new process).
>
> ...
>
> one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using **if
>   __name__ == '__main__'**

So your program should read as follow:

```
import multiprocessing as multi

def worker():
    print "Worker!!!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multi.Process(target = worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice.
However, the result of your suggested code is the same as mine. 
It is really strange.

Comment: @SkyChoi, Did you run it interactive session? or `python script-name.py` ?

Comment: @SkyChoi, Try to run it in terminal (or cmd.exe / powershell if you use Windows).

Comment: @SkyChoi, If you use PyScripter, use `External Run` instead of `Run`.